# Filter array containing regular expression or multiple critera

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am looking to filter a column with anything that starts with either m,n,o. Things work fine when I tried to filter with 2 items but does not work for more than 2 items.

```
Criteria1:="=m*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=n*"
```

Works fine to filter anything that starts with m or n

```
//Criteria1:="=p*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=z*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=e*"
```

Throws error invalid criteria

```
Criteria1:=Array("=mab", "=nab", "oab"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Works fine to filter mab,nab,oab.

```
Criteria1:=Array("=m*", "=n*", "o*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Works fine to filter literally ``m*`,`n*`,`o*` (it is not being considered as regular expression), what i am looking is to filter anything that starts with m or n or o

Comment: Try with `^[mno]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using advanced filter in that way (suppose the field is column A)

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        .Range("H2").Formula = "=OR(LEFT(A2,1)=""m"",LEFT(A2,1)=""n"",LEFT(A2,1)=""o"")"
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=.Range("H1:H2"), Unique:=False
        .Range("H2").ClearContents
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks. But I observed that I am unable to perform undo using `ctrl+z`

Comment: As for running VBA macros there is no undo. You would make a reverse code that show all the data .. Notice the code and you can create such a  code